# Conditional sum values by adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Through some code I already came up to this reduction of an original database. Column `STA_SID` can have different values, some can be repeated. Column `CC_SI` can have only three values - `ESS`, `VSS` or `Ostali nameni`.

The final thing I'd like to do is: add a new column, where for each unique values in `STA_SID`, `sum` column `Au` by values in `CC_SI` for each of  three possible values and for the one, where the value presents more than 50% of the entire `Au` for `STA_SID`, assign that `CC_SI`.

```
     STA_SID          CC_SI     Au
0   10001082  Ostali nameni  226.9
1   10001082            VSS  164.9
2   10001087  Ostali nameni   13.5
3   10001089  Ostali nameni   48.6
4   10001092  Ostali nameni   49.5
5   10001093            ESS  151.9
6   10001094  Ostali nameni    8.0
7   10001098  Ostali nameni   18.0
8   10001112  Ostali nameni   61.0
9   10001113  Ostali nameni   49.5
10  10001115            ESS   89.1
11  10001116            ESS   78.0
12  10001117            ESS  103.0
13  10001118            ESS   70.0
14  10001121            ESS  102.2
```

Example:

`CC_SI` = 10001082

Sum of `Au` = 226,9 + 164,9 = 391,8

`Au` of `Ostali nameni` for `STA_SID = 10001082` equals `226,9` which is more than 50% of 391,8.

Final df would look like this for `STA_SID = 10001082`

```
     STA_SID          CC_SI     Au            NewColumn
0   10001082  Ostali nameni  226.9       Ostali nameni
1   10001082            VSS  164.9       Ostali nameni
```

I tried to write this swiftly with a single line with `lambda` but i couldn't sum the values from other rows. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find it this way, by getting the proportions of Au for each record compared to its group, determining which record will determine the CC_SI for its group, then applying that value back to each group.

```
df['Au_Proportion'] = df['Au']/df['Au'].groupby(df["STA_SID"]).transform('sum')
df['Majority'] = df['Au_Proportion'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >.5 else 0)
df['Group_CC_SI'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['CC_SI'].loc[(df['Majority']==1)&(df['STA_SID']==x['STA_SID'])].values[0],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great on my "demo database". When i run the code through the entire database which includes several thousands of rows, i get the error `'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' ` Do you have any idea why? The program points out the command `df['Group_CC_SI'] = df.apply(lambda x: ... ` as the one where the problem lies

Comment: I honestly wouldn't be able to tell without more information about the new data you're running it on and where the effects might be differing. What I can tell you is that it has to do with the part of the command ".values[0]". In the code I wrote, you're getting a series with a single value and that bit I quoted pulls out the value itself. Values returns a numpy array and the error message you're getting is suggesting that it's not pulling any array at all.

Comment: My guess would be look to where the test and real data might be differing, especially in terms of metadata. Maybe a column is capitalized in the code but not the new database?